# Getting data from HTML input fields to AJAX and declaring to data method

Tags: php, html, ajax

Good day! Me and my colleagues studying AJAX almost two weeks and we had difficulties in getting the data from input fields from HTML and transferring it to AJAX.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addmarble").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //var image = document.getElementById("#Marble_Img").files[0];
        /*var image = $("#Marble_Img").val();   
        var desc = $("#Marble_Desc").val(); 
        var size = $("#Marble_Size").val(); 
        var thickness = $("#Marble_Thickness").val();   
        var supplier = $("#Marble_Supplier").val(); 
        var quantity = $("#Marble_Quantity").val(); 
        var submit = $("#Marble_Submit").val(); */  
        var image = $("MarbleImg").val();   
        var desc = $("MarbleDesc").val();   
        var size = $("MarbleSize").val();   
        var thickness = $("MarbleThickness").val(); 
        var supplier = $("MarbleSupplier").val();   
        var quantity = $("MarbleQty").val();    
        var submit = $("submit").val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",        // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data:{
            image: image,
            desc: desc,
            size: size,
            thickness: thickness,
            supplier: supplier,
            quantity: quantity,
            submit: submit
            },// Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
        alert("noice"); 
        console.log(data);  
        }

        })

        }));

        });
    </script>
```

It prompts that we get the data from the input fields but the data returns undefined.

How to fix them? Thanks!

Comment: _" but the data returns undefined"_ - thought about posting the code that would _return_ the data? (which would be upload.php)

Comment: additionally: did you check network-tab to see what is actually returned? What is `console.log(data)` giving you? Just 'undefined'?

Comment: 3rd: `$("MarbleImg")` is searching for an element `<MarbleImg>`. I suppose you want the id (`<input id='MarbleImg'>`), which would be `$("#MarbleImg")`

Comment: If these MarbleImg, MarbleDesc, MarbleSize etc are your ids in html element then it should start with a # symbol